# Adding input with simple_form to get <datalist>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form-for

I am trying to use simple_form to generate an input textfield with collections, equal to

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
<option value="Internet Explorer">
<option value="Firefox">
<option value="Chrome">
<option value="Opera">
<option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

something to be like:
[image]

Comment: where this list of browsers have been saved?

Comment: in @vendor_categories

Answer (score 1):

Apparently simple_form has [discussed adding this feature](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1539) and decided [currently not to implement](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1539#issuecomment-463204874) it (February 2019).

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
<%= form.input :browsers, input_html: { list: "browsers" } %>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
<%= f.select :browsers, ["Internet Explorer", "Firefox", "Chrome", "Opera", "Safari"]%>
```